# passing url parameters to other page using express and node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

so i have a chat app that i am working on  [here](https://niknet.ddns.net) and i am trying to make it to where a user can type in like https://niknet.ddns.net/room/randomroomUID and it will join them to that room if they are logged in (i use password for handling login and signup) my code looks like this on my routes.js (in case you dont know it's the js that handles all my express stuff)

i tried this

```
app.get('/room/:roomUid', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.params.roomUid)
    console.log(req.user)
    res.cookie('uid',req.user.uid, { maxAge: 999999999999999999999});
    var username = req.user.displayName;
    app.post( 'apolloMainchat',{ roomUid:req.params.roomUid , username});
  });
```

but im not sure how to pass the information across to the express code that handles when users `/apolloMainchat`

typically a user can get to `/apolloMainchat` like this

```
app.get('/apolloMainchat', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.user)
    res.cookie('uid',req.user.uid, { maxAge: 999999999999999999999});
    var username = req.user.displayName;
    res.render('apolloMainchat.ejs', username);
    console.log(req.user.displayName)
});
```

any one know how to help me?

Comment: For me it seems unclear what you are asking. That `app.post` makes no sense once it is inside a request handler. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Are you trying to redirect the user to `/apolloMainchat`? If thats the case you should replace `app.post('/app..` with `res.redirect('/apolloMainchat')`

Comment: @RenatoGama thank you for your quick response i replaced my code with what your suggested and now i am confused on how to access that when i'm on the /apolloMainchat page

Answer (score 0):

You will want to pass this by redirecting the client to a new endpoint and then reading those parameters from the query as Renato Gama said in the comments.

Your code will then become something like this.

```
app.get('/room/:roomUid', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
    res.cookie('uid',req.user.uid, { maxAge: 999999999999999999999});
    app.redirect('apolloMainchat?roomUid=' + req.params.roomUid);
});

app.get('/apolloMainchat', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.params.roomUid);
});
```

You're just using a HTTP redirect to pass them to the new endpoint and attaching the data as a query parameter as you would if they requested it directly. It's not quite clear what you're trying to achieve, but this should do what you've described.